# VBA Paste Data After Other VBA Copied Data

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to have a "Called Sub" paste data after the last row used in the one that is calling the code.

However, I can only manage to have the first sub to paste the first data selected and when "ESTDEUDA" is called it pastes the other data on information first used.

```
Sub ActualizarFondos()

'Deuda
J = 12

For i = 15 To 26
Sheets("Reporte").Activate

If Cells(i, "C").Value > 0 Then
Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "B")).Copy

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(J, "Z"), Cells(J, "AA")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

'Call ESTDEUDA

J = J + 1

End If

Next

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ESTDEUDA()

J = 12

For i = 3 To 6
Sheets("FondosEstrategia").Activate

If Cells(i, "F").Value > 0 Then
Range(Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "F")).Select
Range(Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy


Sheets("Reporte").Activate
Range(Cells(J, "Z"), Cells(J, "AA")).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

J = J + 1

End If


End Sub
```

I'd like to know what can be done in order to have the information from sheet "FondosEstrategia" to be pasted after the infomation pasted from sheet "Reporte".

Is there any way that a kind of J = J +1 is applied to "ESTDEUDA" in order to paste after J = J +1 from "ActualizarFondos".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `J`. Just offset your `i` value in your first loop to produce desired `J` value.

---

**On your first loop:**
`i = 15`
`J = 12` which is the same is `i - 3`.

Therefore, you can swap out every instance of `J` with `i - 3`.

Next, you can pass `i` as a parameter (input) into `ESTDEUDA` using the below method.

```
Sub ActualizarFondos()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 15 To 26
    With Sheets("Reporte")
        If .Cells(i, "C").Value > 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, "C"), .Cells(i, "B")).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WHATSHEET").Range("Z" & i - 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Call ESTDEUDA(i)

        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ESTDEUDA(i As Integer)

Dim x As Long

For x = 3 To 6
    With Sheets("FondosEstrategia")
        If .Cells(x, "F").Value > 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(x, "E"), .Cells(x, "F")).Copy
            Sheets("Reporte").Range("Z" & i - 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Also, you need to qualify your instances of `Range` and `Cells` with a direct sheet. You should avoid relying to `Active` or `Selected` sheet.